# png in div appears in Firefox, not in Iexplorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can someone explain me why the following css isn't working for iexplorer 8?

```
.rounded_corners{

background: url(../images/achtergrond_homepage.png)no-repeat left bottom;
display: block;
left: 480px;
top: 130px;
z-index: 100000;
position: absolute;
color:#FFF;
padding: 15px;
width: 360px;
height: 470px;

}
```

Comment: "png)no-repeat" => "png) no-repeat" maybe ?

Comment: Indeed, almost, You lead me to the sollution. It's background: url(../images/achtergrond_homepage.png); no-repeat left bottom;

Strange that FF does the trick and ie stays behind.

Comment: I made my comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that

```
background: url(../images/achtergrond_homepage.png)no-repeat left bottom;
```

should most likely be

```
background: url(../images/achtergrond_homepage.png) no-repeat left bottom;
```